# Add new line spaces between elements of an htmltools::tagList in an Rmarkdown html page

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, taglist, htmltools

I using `htmltools::tagList` to display a list of plots in an `Rmarkdown` `html` page.

Let's say my list of plots is:

```
set.seed(1)
plot.list <- lapply(1:3,
                    function(i) plotly::plot_ly(x=paste0(c("a", "b", "c"), ":", i), 
                                                y=paste0(c("d", "e", "f"), ":", i), 
                                                z=matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3), 
                                                type="heatmap"))
```

And then I'm displaying them in an `Rmarkdown` using this code:

````
```{r display.plot, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::tagList(plot.list)
```
````

The problem is that they come out with no new line spacing between them. So my question is how do I add new line spacing between them?